# Java Generics: Concrete type of a parent parent relationship?

Tags: java, android

So I have an issues where I am trying to implement a concrete version of a parent's parent as follows.

```
public abstract class Collection<E> {
...
}

public abstract class Search extends Collection {
...
}
```

My question is how exactly do I setup a new class, let's say Contacts, so I can do the following.

```
public class Contacts extends Search<Contact> (which means really Collection<Contact>) {
...
}
```

Is there a way to do this? Or do I need to I need the relationship between Contact and Collection not to go through search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public abstract class Search<E> extends Collection<E>
```

The rest are fine, this should work.

Comment: Thanks that's the solution, will accept when I can!